# R not showing in Terminal

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I'm new to VS Code and am trying to use R there. I think I have it set-up correctly with all required sub-programs installed. When attempting to print "Hello World", the output tab produces messages that makes me think VS Code is recognizing the R code. Also, I can hover over my R code in VS Code and the hints pop up explaining the R functions; so I did something right I think.

I noticed that the bottom right of the VS Code screen says "R: (not attached)"

When I click on that and try to attach it, I get this:

```
PS C:\Users\Bob > .vsc.attach()
At line:1 char:13
+ .vsc.attach()
+             ~
An expression was expected after '('.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpectedExpression
```

In the terminal, if I click the down arrow next to Powershell, I get these options:

```
PowerShell(Default)
Command Prompt
JavaScipt Debug Terminal
Split Terminal
Configure Terminal Settings
Select Default Profile
```

To get to my JSON file, I go to View >> Command Pallette  then type "Open Settings JSON". It contains this:

```
{
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Light+",
    "r.alwaysUseActiveTerminal": true,
    "r.rpath.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\x64\\R.exe",
    "security.workspace.trust.untrustedFiles": "open",
    "files.associations": {
        "*.R": "r"
    },
    "r.lsp.debug": true,
    "r.rterm.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\x64\\R.exe",
    "r.bracketedPaste": true,
    "r.source.focus": "terminal",
    "r.rterm.option": [
        "--no-save",
        "--no-restore",
        "--r-binary=C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\R.exe"
    ],
    "terminal.external.windowsExec": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\R.exe"
}
```

I am not using radian right now. I want to get basic R working in VSCode then I'll connect with Radian.

It keeps trying to run my R script using PowerShell and I think this is the main problem. What do I do to get it to run using R? Thanks.

Comment: Correct: it's inputting your R script into a Powershell terminal. You need to switch the terminal to R. To the top right of the console window it should say "powershell +v". Click on the 'v' down arrow. If R is an option, click on it. If it's not an option, or if you want to make R the default terminal, you need to adjust your JSON settings: `View > Command Palette > Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`.

Comment: I entered all the correct path details into the settings of VS Code; still not working. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: So in the terminal drop-down menu (i.e. "powershell +v"), what terminal options are available to you? Are you using R or Radian? Can you share what setup instructions you used? Can you  edit your question above to show your JSON Settings so that we can check to see if it's setup correctly (if so, be sure to swap out any identifying information with generic equivalents)?

Comment: coip, I've added the info you requested. Thanks.

Comment: First, try changing both "r.rpath.windows" and "r.rterm.windows" from "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\x64\\R.exe" to "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\R.exe" (that is, get rid of the "\\x64"--and don't worry: it should still load of 64-bit R). Then save it , restart VSCode, and see if R shows up as a terminal option after clicking the down arrow next to Powershell. If it's there, click on it to switch to an R terminal and then try running your R script. If this doesn't work, let me know as I have another idea on how to solve it.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I've written up my comments as a formal solution below in case it helps someone else out in the future. I've also added information about making R your default terminal. As you're new to Stack Overflow, just to let you know, you can select the solution as a valid answer and it'll give you points that will help you build towards unlocking additional features (like voting).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what is in your JSON settings, it should work if you remove the `\\x64` portion of your `r.path.windows` and `r.term.windows` paths:

```
"r.rpath.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\R.exe",
"r.rterm.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.2\\bin\\R.exe",
// truncated
```

After changing that, you should be able to switch to an R terminal by using the drop-down menu in the terminal window.

Additionally, you can set R to be your default terminal by adding an additional line to your JSON Settings:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "R",
// truncated
```